# show observation that got lost in merge

Tags: dataframe, datatable

Lets say I want to merge two different dataframes by the key of two columns.

Dataframe One has 70000 obs of 10 variables.
Dataframe Two has 4500 obs of   5 variables.

Now I checked how my observations from my New dataframe are left by using this code.
So I realize that my columns from my dataframe Two are now only 4490 obs of 10 variables.
Thats all right.
My question is:
Is there way of giving me back the 5 observations from my dataframe Two I lost during the process. The names would be enough.

Thank you :)

Comment: You lost them probably because those 5 obs didn't match with any obs in `ONE` and you were using a left join with `all.x = TRUE`. If you want to keep all obs from both datasets, just change `all.x = TRUE` to `all = TRUE`. This will make it a full outer join.

Comment: Well you will have to define "gives me back those 5 names". In what format do you want them to be in? A separate dataframe, a vector or something else?

Comment: perhaps `anti_join` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `dplyr::anti_join` for this. From its documentation:

> return all rows from x where there are not matching values in y, keeping just columns from x.

You'd probably have to pass your data frame `TWO` as `x`.

EDIT: as mentioned in the comments, the syntax for its `by` argument is different.

Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name=c("a", "b", "c"),
                  Date1=c(1,2,3),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Name=c("a", "d"),
                  Date2=c(1,2),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

> dplyr::anti_join(df2, df1, by=c("Name"="Name", "Date2"="Date1"))
  Name Date
1    d    2
```

Comment: (Not my downvote). You can supply different names to the `by` argument. So it is not true that key variables "must have same names"

Comment: Using different names and specifying `by=c("Name", "Date1", "Date2")` results in `Error: 'by' can't contain join column 'Date1' which is missing from LHS`

Comment: The correct syntax is `anti_join(df2, df1, by=c("Name2"="Name1", "Date2"="Date1"))` assuming `Name2` and `Date2` comes from `df2`

Comment: That I did not know, nifty.

Comment: Feel free to add that to your answer. Otherwise, good solution.